# Section for point in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cgpoint

[-[UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForRowAtPoint:) returns an index path given a CGPoint. However, it only works when the CGPoint lies exactly on a cell. If the point happens to be on the header or footer of a section, it returns nil.

Given a CGPoint, how can I get the section at that point which doesn't fail in the case of header/footer?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the following extension method, which relies on [-rectForSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/rectForSection:). Depending on your needs, you may want to use [-rectForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/rectForHeaderInSection:) or [-rectForFooterInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/rectForFooterInSection:) instead.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)xyz_indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    if (indexPath) {
        return indexPath;
    }

    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < [self numberOfSections]; section++) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([self rectForSection:section], point)) {
            return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a specific method for that.

If `[UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:]` returns `nil`, you could add or subtract a few pixels from the point's Y-coordinate (preferably the sum of the footer height and header height), and see if this method returns a value. If it does, you obtain a section number close to the original point, and use the `- rectForSection:` method or the `- rectForFooterInSection:` and `- rectForHeaderInSection:` methods to get the exact section.